# Bootstrap 3 affix not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This sounds like a noob question but I cant get the affix to work. The second column moves to the left as soon as I scroll. Im guessing a CSS positioning issue? What am I doing wrong:
http://jsfiddle.net/8pbebr21/

I have the initialization as below:

```
$("#TOC").affix();
```

Comment: Have you find your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : http://jsfiddle.net/8pbebr21/2/

*Just wrap the `div#TOC` inside a container, and specify `.affix` css*

**HTML** :

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" >
            <div id="TOC">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam accumsan eget arcu nec placerat. Cras ultrices nisl vitae interdum accumsan. Fusce a nisi placerat turpis varius pulvinar. Donec ultrices turpis in nisl fringilla ornare non a eros. Praesent aliquet elit et scelerisque luctus. Vivamus in elit at tellus elementum ullamcorper.</div></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.affix{
    width:25%;
    padding-right:15px;
}
```